# What is the meaning of zero voltage switching (ZVS) and zero current switching (ZCS)?

Tags: switching, zvs

I was reading about induction heating circuits in a electronics textbook and saw the terms `ZVS` and `ZCS` which are abbreviation for `Zero Voltage Switching` and `Zero Current Switching` respectively. There are many academic articles about these topics, but for a novice like me these articles are very theoretical and i can't get a grasp of topic. I would be happy if someone could help me and explain the idea behind `ZVS` and `ZCS`.

Answer (score 5):

That's actually pretty simple:

In many situations, you need to switch a load on and off – for example, to dim a lamp.

It's often advantageous to switch something when either the current flowing is zero, or the voltage across the load is zero.

Now, if your load is a pure resistance, then the point where zero current flows is exactly the point where zero voltage happens.

But for things like inductive or capacitive loads, that's not the case – current and voltage are out of phase for these kinds of loads.

The motivation to do something like switching a load when the current is zero is that this means you don't get \$\frac{\partial\,i(t)}{\partial t}\rightarrow \infty\$ that you'd get when switching off something when a current is flowing. And because of the physical laws, having a high \$\frac{\partial\,i(t)}{\partial t}\$ in an inductor is very bad – because it will cause a voltage peak of a very high amplitude!

Comment: ...resulting in the counter-intuitive result that the best time to switch a pure inductive load is at peak voltage!

Comment: @Ian Bland- By peak voltage, do you mean the back emf?

Comment: SMPS should get mentioned here. I've seen buck converters in the 99% efficiency range.

Comment: @VinitShandilya at the peak of the supply. The current should be passing through the zero point (ideal model) at that instant.

Answer (score 3):

Terms `Zero Voltage Switching`and `Zero Current Switching` are very unfortunate and misleading. More appropriate terms would be `Zero Voltage Turn-on` and `Zero Current Turnoff`.

The idea is pretty obvious: for the switch itself it is advantageous to be turned on a tad before there will be current through it, and turned off when current is already ceased.

Comment: Zero-voltage switching can be done at turn on or turn off so there's no problem with that expression but I'll agree that zero-current switching doesn't make much sense in the off to on condition.